# How to get user input in awk script

Tags: scripts, awk

I'm writing an awk script that calculates some statistics. First I need to get an user input, which is a string, and store it in a variable (center). I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

printf "Enter the type of school (AFA, CEE, CFA, EASD):"
read center
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `getline` to read from the special filename `/dev/stdin`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  printf "Enter the type of school (AFA, CEE, CFA, EASD): "
  getline center < "/dev/stdin"
}

{
  print center, $0
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the user input without using BEGIN?

Comment: @sergei yes - `getline` may be used anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this: is it possible to print the string "Enter the type of school (AFA, CEE, CFA, EASD):" without using BEGIN (with printf or something similar)?

Comment: @sergei everything in awk is either a PATTERN or an ACTION. Except for `BEGIN` and `END`, each PATTERN is evaluated for every record in the input. If you want the user to be prompted to enter a type of school for each record, then remove the `BEGIN` pattern. If that's not what you want, then I suggest you edit your question to clarify your requirements.